# Windows limitation in PCB window in Altium

Tags: altium

Is there any window limitation in PCB window in Altium? because I can't move my mouse cursor -180.086 on the x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're hitting the absolute origin of the workspace. Move your relative origin further to the right and it should keep you away from the workspace limitations in the software. You can change the relative origin by using Edit -> Origin -> Set, or "E O S" as a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, But it doesn't do anything and the limitation is exist.

Comment: It never allows you to move your relative origin into the negative workspace either.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Altium 20.0 designer documetation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/more-about-pcb-design-ad)

> The board can range in size from the miniscule, right up to 100x100 inches, using design objects down to 0.001mil in size.

100 inch = 2540 mm

Maybe your board runs from to + 2360 mm, so you hit the max board dimensions at -180 mm?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, No all my components by considering their size is less than 530mm.