# Altium won't let me move object to negative coordinates

Tags: altium

I have imported a BRD document from Orcad to Altium. The origin is on the top left of the board and I can't move things or draw traces below or to the left of the origin, that is, negative coordinate levels, Altium just locks the mouse pointer and it doesn't move.

Is this a configuration inside Altium or is it a bug?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you?
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/466701/41856

Comment: Interesting... that appears to be it... I already moved it all, just was hoping there was a better way to solve this, thanks!

Comment: I pretty much never use the absolute origin, I always create a relative origin way off in "positive space" and design my board around that

Comment: Me too, but this project was imported from Orcad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a limit to how far you can go negative. Ctrl-A to select all and cut and paste in the positive quadrant, then move the origin to where you want it. Edit->Origin->Set

It also gets messy sometimes when parts end up way off the page.

Comment: Pretty buggy that the import doesn't take care of this, thanks!

Comment: I had issues where the connectors went out over the board edege in negative Y. DRC failed and i could not expand the room. Ctrl-A, move then Edit->Origin-> Set resolved my issue. Thanks!